# Interactive CLI-type web app

Tags: console

I am trying to make a personal website in which users can type in "commands" to display information -- like how UNIX commands work (e.g. type in about for About Me or contact for Contact Details, or ls for a listing of all links).

I searched online hoping to find some tutorials, but most of what I could find was related to opening websites through the command line (maybe I'm just bad at Google search).

Examples of what I'm trying to achieve are plenty: http://cb.vu/, and of course, codecademy and tryruby.

I'd greatly appreciate if some one could point me in the right direction as to what languages/frameworks would I need to learn to be able to move ahead with my project.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cb.vu website uses a javascript terminal simulator from:
http://www.masswerk.at/termlib/

There are several other similar projects which do this.

Basic idea being able to get user input and then do a call to the server and then show the output.

Its not terribly difficult to do from scratch but if you are looking for an authentic unix terminal console and don't want to do something original then you can find them thru google.

Several web emulators of 8bit machines and code execution environments are built around this idea, so those are good places to dig around.